# Why set state when this.props.value === undefined in Input component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I've just found the following code in antd's Input component and I don't understand why `if (this.props.value === undefined)` is used here. Can someone explain to me what it does?

```
setValue(value: string, callback?: () => void) {
    if (this.props.value === undefined) {
      this.setState({ value }, callback);
    } else {
      callback?.();
    }
  }
```

The full code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/input/Input.tsx#L246).

Comment: Checks if there was a `value` property in the state before it is changed...

Answer (score 1):

`this.props.value === undefined` is used to check if component is in "uncontrolled" mode, ie is using internal state to keep value.

[Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)